# BigQuery - reshape table to vector

Tags: vector, google-bigquery

I have a table with

```
zip_client    zip_supplier     zip_store
12345         56432            42374
35424         null             12345         
etc
```

And I need to get overall unique zips.

Is there a simple way to do it within a query?
Currently I download the result into Sheets and do it there.
If there was some kind of `reshape` in BigQuery it would be very easy, but I could not find how to do it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Legacy SQL

```sql
#legacySQL
SELECT 
  type, zip
FROM 
  (SELECT 'client'   AS type, zip_client   AS zip FROM yourTable),
  (SELECT 'supplier' AS type, zip_supplier AS zip FROM yourTable),
  (SELECT 'store'    AS type, zip_store    AS zip FROM yourTable)
WHERE NOT zip IS NULL
```

if you will have chance or decide to migrate to BigQuery Standard SQL - see below

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT zip.type, zip.zip
FROM yourTable, 
UNNEST([STRUCT<type STRING, zip INT64>
  ('client', zip_client), 
  ('supplier', zip_supplier), 
  ('store', zip_store)]) AS zip
WHERE NOT zip.zip IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/):

```
SELECT DISTINCT zip
FROM YourTable
CROSS JOIN UNNEST([zip_client, zip_supplier, zip_store]) AS zip;
```

You can put any number of columns inside the UNNEST depending on the structure of your table.

Comment: Thank you. How would it look in Legacy as the whole request is supposed to be part of a bigger query that is written in Legacy SQL?